# SQL: Query Dependent Records Through An I/O Pivot Table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, relationship

I have a question regarding the extract of a schema you see below:

[image: Example SQL Schema]

As you see there are `tasks` that are connected with `files` through a pivot table `task_files`.
The pivot table has an enum column `io` with possible values `input` and `output`.

I would like to create a SQL query that searches dependent tasks of a task.
Without any further constraints the query should return all tasks that depend on at least one output file of another task.
In a second step I want to filter it to only return tasks depending on output files of a specific task.

Comment: Are you looking to do this in raw SQL, or Laravel Eloquent code?

Comment: I just removed all refereces to Laravel from the question ;) However, the aim is still a laravel relation or at least an implementation with the query builder. But it would be a nice start to have some raw query working.

Comment: OK. Could you add your SQL that you have presently, to give readers an idea of the direction you are travelling in?

Comment: I would like to answer this question myself, because I just figured out a query. And I would like to ask a new question to get some help with converting it to laravel.

Comment: You can ask a new question about the Laravel issue. You could try to edit this question to improve it with regards to the SQL-only issue - but I am not sure it is worth the effort. The improve this one I would suggest showing what work you had before you solved it, plus some initial data rows, the expected output, and the actual output. If you can make those edits, it can be reopened, and then you can add a self-answer if you wish.